# Android ABS center title with home button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I managed to center the title of the ABS using a custom view but the home button is gone. How can this be solved? Is the only way to do it to put this home button in the custom view? (To be clear: the home button should be on the left not in the center)

Custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.widget_actionbar_title);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this code to make it work:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: this does not answer the q u originally posted , nor does it make both the custom layout AND the home button visable

Comment: I think you still need to set the icon in the styles.xml and set the style in the manifest.

Answer (score 4):

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    View customView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.app_icon, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customView, params);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_button));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM  | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

Answer (score 1):

solution is very simple)
Change in your Layout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

on this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

it will help because your initial layout takes all visible place and there is no place for "home"